# Outlook 2013 VBA How to Display Modeless Dialog Box

Tags: vba, outlook

I have VBA code that runs every time a new email message is received.  It has several processing steps including creating excel spreadsheets, so can take a minute or two to execute.

I would like to display a modeless dialog box that shows updated status messages as processing of the email progresses.  I created a UserForm1, but can't figure out how to instantiate it from the VBA code.

Comment: Do you need a `UserForm`. Maybe a custom MsgBox will do. See here http://www.analystcave.com/tutorials/excel-vba-tutorial/#Excel_VBA_Tutorial_MessageBox_and_User_Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final version of the test code after receiving info from @AnalystCave.com follows.  Still working on how to force the userform to stay on top of the other windows.

```
Public Sub TestForm()

  Dim uf As UserForm1
  Set uf = New UserForm1

  Load uf

  uf.Show vbModeless
  uf.msgStatus.Text = "11111111111111111"
  uf.msgStatus.Text = "22222222222222222"
  uf.msgStatus.Text = "33333333333333333"
  uf.Hide

  Unload uf

End Sub
```

In my particular application, what appears on the desktop is predictable.  In this case, one way to solve the problem is:

```
''' execute something that you know will show on top of the userform then

uf.Show vbModeless      ' this will put the userform back on top
```

Comment: See my updated answer. Use the `SetWindowTopMost` function

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```
Dim uf As UserForm1
Set uf = New UserForm1
uf.Show False
```

However, this is not a good practice as a notification should be modal. Maybe you want `SystemModal` (in front of ALL windows) instead of `ApplicationModal` (in front of Application)? The VBA MsgBox can be quite customized actually so check out [this post here to learn more on how to customize a MsgBox](http://www.analystcave.com/tutorials/excel-vba-tutorial/#Excel_VBA_Tutorial_MessageBox_and_User_Forms).

### To make a Window TopMost

If you want your Form window to be TopMost try this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/184297

```
  Option Explicit
  Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = 2
  Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = 1
  Public Const FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
  Public Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
  Public Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2

  Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowPos"  _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
        ByVal x As Long, _
        ByVal y As Long, _
        ByVal cx As Long, _
        ByVal cy As Long, _
        ByVal wFlags As Long  ) As Long

  Public Function SetTopMostWindow(hwnd As Long, Topmost As Boolean) _
     As Long

     If Topmost = True Then 'Make the window topmost
        SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, _
           0, FLAGS)
     Else
        SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, _
           0, 0,FLAGS)
        SetTopMostWindow = False
     End If
  End Function
```

To use this on your form:

```
 res = SetTopMostWindow(uf.hwnd, True)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  I do want the messages to be in front of all windows, but the application has to run unattended, so I believe this means it needs to be modeless.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good reference.  But for others that may run across this question, please note that this applies to VB.  To use in Outlook VBA will require some slight modification.